# Paginação com DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-datatables, datatable

Olá,

Estou usando uma biblioteca chamada "DataTables" que é uma biblioteca que permite adicionar recursos de interatividade e manipulação de elementos de tabelas no HTML.

Entretanto, mesmo seguindo a documentação e tentando personalizar a atualização dos atributos, porém a listagem da API que possui 20 elementos só aparece 10 e não mostra a páginação no canto inferior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

        <!--jQuery-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <!-- DATA TABLES -->
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
         <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <!--Deixar em portugues o datatables-->
         <script src="./pt-BR.json"></script>


</head>
<body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Item</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">
            <!-- Os itens da tabela serão adicionados dinamicamente aqui pelo JavaScript -->
                
            </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script>

    let qtdElementosPorPagina;
    let paginaAtual;


    let testeNovo;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        let teste = null;

        $('#dataTable').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/lista',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (d) {
                    // Adicione as variáveis customizadas aos parâmetros da solicitação
                    d.start = 0;
                    d.length = qtdElementosPorPagina;
                    d.start = paginaAtual;
                    
                    d.page = paginaAtual; // Corrigido para 'page'

                    console.log(d);

                    teste = d;

                    // Retorne os parâmetros modificados
                    return d;
                },
                dataSrc: function(json) {
                    // Este bloco de código é executado após a conclusão bem-sucedida da solicitação Ajax
                    console.log("Dados de sucesso:", json);
                    
                    testeNovo = json;

                    qtdElementosPorPagina = json.pageable.pageSize;
                    paginaAtual = json.pageable.pageNumber;

                    return json.content; // Retorna a propriedade 'content' como fonte de dados
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    // Lide com erros, se necessário
                    console.error("Erro na requisição Ajax:", textStatus, error);
                }
            },
            columns: [
                { data: 'id' },
                { data: 'item' },
                { data: 'description' }
            ],
            paging: true,
            language: {
                url: "./pt-BR.json"
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

mostrando o seguinte texto:

Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registro(s) (Filtrados de NaN registros)
Anterior12345…NaNPróximo

O json é este:

```
{"content":[{"id":1,"item":"item 1","description":"describe 1"},{"id":2,"item":"item 2","description":"describe 2"},{"id":3,"item":"item 3","description":"describe 3"},{"id":4,"item":"item 4","description":"describe 4"},{"id":5,"item":"item 5","description":"describe 5"},{"id":6,"item":"item 6","description":"describe 6"},{"id":7,"item":"item 7","description":"describe 7"},{"id":8,"item":"item 8","description":"describe 8"},{"id":9,"item":"item 9","description":"describe 9"},{"id":10,"item":"item 10","description":"describe 10"}],"pageable":{"sort":{"empty":true,"sorted":false,"unsorted":true},"offset":0,"pageNumber":0,"pageSize":10,"paged":true,"unpaged":false},"totalPages":2,"totalElements":20,"last":false,"size":10,"number":0,"sort":{"empty":true,"sorted":false,"unsorted":true},"numberOfElements":10,"first":true,"empty":false}
```

Pelo endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8080/lista
```

Fonte:

- - Link de chamada ajax  para carregar a tabela* https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html ;
- - JSON do pt-br: * https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/i18n/pt-BR.json

Answer (score 0):

Tens que adicionar os seguintes dois parâmetros no JSON retornado:

```
"recordsTotal": 20, "recordsFiltered": 20
```